# Multidimensional Array [Multiplication Table]

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

Once again, I need help I finally got the multidimensional array but somehow the display output is not what I want to show..

The code is:

import java.io.*;

public class Multi{
    public static void main(String []args)throws IOException{

```
    int [][] age = new int [10][10];
    int num;

    BufferedReader inpt = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    num=Integer.parseInt(inpt.readLine());

    if (num>0||num<11){
    for(int i=1; i<num; i++){
        System.out.println("\t");
        for(int j=1; j<num; j++){
        age[i][j]=i*j;
        System.out.print(age[i][j]+"\t");
     }
    }
  }
}
```

}

For e.g. 
What's displaying is..

Enter a number: 5

- 1 2 3 4
- 2 4 6 8
- 3 6 9 12
- 4 8 12 16
- 5 10 15 20

What I really want to show is

Enter a number: 5

- 1 2 3 4 5
- 2 4 6 8 10
- 3 6 9 12 15
- 4 8 12 16 20
- 5 10 15 20 25

Are there any alternatives for this code or it's really the way it is?
By the way, thanks in advance!

P.S: I tried using without an array and it works, but somehow I wanted to try it with array this time soo yeah. I'm kinda lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop is going from `i=1` to strictly less than num. So for 5 it does 1,2,3,4 and stops. You might want to start at zero or do a lesser than or equal num.

Idem for your other for loop iterating over `j`.

If you change these :

```
for(int i=1; i<num; i++)
for(int j=1; j<num; j++)
```

with these :

```
for(int i=1; i<=num; i++)
for(int j=1; j<=num; j++)
```

it works just as you want.

---

Just a proposition using `ArrayList` that allows numbers greater than 10 :

```
 public static void main(String []args)throws IOException{


    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> bufferList= new ArrayList<Integer>();;
    int num;

    BufferedReader inpt = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    num=Integer.parseInt(inpt.readLine());

    for(int i=1; i<=num; i++){
        System.out.println("\t");
        bufferList= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int j=1; j<=num; j++){
            bufferList.add(i*j);
        }

        list.add(bufferList);
    }

    for (ArrayList<Integer> alist : list){
        for (Integer a : alist){
            System.out.print(a+"\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: Ugh. THANKS.
I forgot to put an equal sign to make it less than or equal to for these statements: for(int i=1; i<num; i++), for(int j=1; j<num; j++){

Silly me. Lol.

Comment: If it was usefull consider accepting and/or upvoting this answer. Also next time you could use a java Collection (ArrayList for example) instead of an array. It will be more flexible (avoiding the initilization with the magic numbers)